# Square transaction API card tender does not return card expiration date

Tags: square-connect

I'm using the square api sandbox to charge nonce and charge customer profile.
when I charge nonce all the card details : last four, card brand are included in the response except for the expiration date.
`Tender[0].CardDetails.Card.ExpMonth` and ExpYear is null

when I charge profile the same fields return data

is this going to be the case in production? is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information will be a part of the `Charge` response if it was for a card on file (using `customer_id` and `customer_card_id`). If you just call `Charge` using a `card_nonce` rather than a card on file, then the information will not be surfaced.

Comment: Yes my problem is that it returning null for ExpMonth and ExpYear in the charge response If I’m charging a nonce is it a sandbox thing ? Is it going to return the information in production?

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. You're correct, it will only show the expiration month/year in the response if it's a card on file. I'll update my answer.